# Should I unit test these two typescript functions? If so why (or how) . I'm using JEST

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have two functions

```
  public cards?: IDilemmaCard[];
  public selectedCard?: IDilemmaCard;



 public onClickRandomCard(): void {
    if(this.cards)
    this.selectedCard = this.cards[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.cards.length)];
  }

  public onClickDocLink(): boolean|Promise<boolean|PipelineResult> {  
    return this._router.navigateToRoute('introduction', {id: HomeSection.DocumentList});
  }
```

I also have a unit test for one but not the other

```
  it('our selected card be has to be defined', (done: jest.DoneCallback): void => {
    const card: IDilemmaCard = { id: 1, textExplanation: '', textSituation: ['', ''] };
    const testConfiguration: ITestConfiguration = {
      activateArguments: {id: '1'},
      runCustomTests: (sut: TestDilemmaCardsDetail): void => {
          expect(sut.selectedCard).toBeDefined();
      }
    };
    componentTester.test(sutFactory, testConfiguration, done);
  });
```

But I'm doubting on whether this is the right unit test or if I even have to do this unit test.

Thoughts?

Comment: Not sure what your `componentTester` is. But to answer your question, imho there is no reason not to test it. E.g. if this is some kind of component (like a React component) consider implement an integration test, for such interactions like redirecting or similar (if e.g. selectedCard changes the UI in some way).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'll look into it. 
What about the other functions ? 
Should I just call them for the test?

Comment: Technically it is never a bad idea to write tests for code, although simple event handlers (what I assume those are) aren't a very high priority, espescially since they only do one thing in this case.